# SEO report made with HTML, CSS and PHP, using API easy/simple way to convert excisting report to PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I use API to get SEO data from different sites. I have made a report html page where to display results right now. Now I'm supposed to convert the report to PDF for my school work. I already have made the report and all text answers depending on the results. Is there a simple way to convert that existing report to PDF

EDIT:
The idea is that user/client fills in web sites name and email and presses button "get report" or something. Then API updates information in data.json file where i get my results. Then it displays the SEO-report for the requested site with its SEO data. With every report user/client needs to get PDF report of the site he/she requested

Comment: Manually one time, or programatically many times?

Comment: If you just need a web page to be a PDF you can do that with Chrome by selecting `print` and changing the destination.

Comment: @Chris User/customer chooses the web site and API gets the results of the site. Now I have HTML web page created with HTML, PHP and CSS I need to convert to it to PDF every time user/customer "orders" SEO report

Comment: Maybe this is relevant in that case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php.

Comment: thank you for your answers. Started to use php to pdf API whitch makes pdf based on my reposrts url